# Google Sheets: How to input timestamp to every changes made in one cell value field?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp

I’m not an expert in Google Sheets but can anyone can help me on how to ***put a timestamp on every updates made on one certain cell***, please?

Please check link:

[image]

Let’s say that **B2** is the total amount of **B4-B7** and I want to update the **Acct1** from **100.00** to **600.00** that auto updates the **B2** to 1500.00. My question is, how do I keep track the updates that has been made on **B2** i.e., putting timestamps to another sheet or somewhere in the active sheet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to collect all the timestamps (from all updates) or just the most recent one?

Comment: I wanted to collect all the timestamps from all the updates, please.

Answer (score 2):

I've some people keeping them in notes

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.range.setNote(e.range.getNote() + '\n' + new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another sheet for logging. And in `onEdit`, you can log the changed information to the sheet.

Following is an example code.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  try{
    var dataSheetName = "Sheet1";
    var logSheetName = "Sheet2";

    if ( SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName() !== dataSheetName ){ // check it is the target sheet name
      return;
    }
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
    var col = range.getColumn();
    if ( row < 3 || col !== 2 ){ // check it is Amount cell.
      return;
    }

    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dataSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(dataSheetName);
    var logSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(logSheetName);
    var nextRow = logSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

    // set timestamp
    logSheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(new Date());
    // copy data
    var srcRange = dataSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2);
    var dstRange = logSheet.getRange(nextRow, 2, 1, 2);
    dstRange.setValues(srcRange.getValues());
  }
  catch(e){
    Browser.msgBox(e);
  }
}
```

I made an example spreadsheet, feel free to make a copy and check the behavior.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g0pL7hwuzaS5Yr7Dh7hm_SyRG5TYxwwrlND2Zx3Bo7w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this using just google sheets...I got it off a youtube video.

Basically `=ifs(A1="","",B1<>"",B1,1*1,now())`

It prompts a circular dependency error so just turn that on (**files-->settings-->calculation** and set to 1.
It's awesome...I use it for time stamping my bills/todo list.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT3ON.jpg)